# Windows Phone 8 SDK - WebBrowser Control - How to refresh page from code

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How can I refresh the webbrowser control from the code behind?
I am using Windows 8 SDK & C#.

Comment: Refresh as in refresh the currently displayed page?

Comment: Yes, the current page.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by storing the most recent visited Url then when you need to refresh you just navigate to it.

```cs
private void browser_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e) {
  lastUri = e.Uri;
}

private void Refresh() {
  browser.Navigate(lastUri);
}
```

Comment: The problem with that is that it only reloads the same page, but if there is form data, then there is an issue with it.  Such as session or viewstate information.

Comment: Form data will be lost anyway since there was no trip to the server unless you are doing ajax updates on the web page. What are you trying to accomplish with the refresh exactly?

Comment: Trying to simulate the F5 key that you would use in your browser.

Comment: The solution I gave you does exactly that. Session will be kept, try login to some site then execute the refresh code. You won't be signed out.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this via injecting JS into the page via the browser contr:

```
var js = "window.location.reload(true);";
Browser.InvokeScript("eval", js);
```

Answer (score 1):

Would be this way;

```
Browser.Navigate(new Uri(Browser.Source.AbsoluteUri));
```